# Getting x in terms of y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this equation:

$$\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{y-x}{x}$$

How would I separate $x$ and $y$ in $x^2+xy-y^2=0$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x$ and by $y$.

Comment: Take new variable $z=\frac{x}{y}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$x^2 + xy - y^2 = 0$$
$$\frac{x^2}{y^2} + \frac{x}{y} - 1 = 0$$
So let $t = \frac{x}{y}$, giving $t^2 + t - 1 = 0$. Can you solve this equation for $t$, giving you a relation between $x$ and $y$ as required?

Comment: Yeap!! there were so many ways

Answer (score 3):

If

$\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{y-x}{x}, \tag 1$

then, assuming $x \ne 0 \ne y$, as we must for the equation to make sense, we may set

$\alpha = \dfrac{x}{y}, \tag 2$

and writing (1) as

$\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{y}{x} - 1, \tag 3$

we find

$\alpha = \alpha^{-1} - 1, \tag 4$

or

$\alpha^2 = 1 - \alpha, \tag 5$

or

$\alpha^2 + \alpha - 1 = 0; \tag 6$

then the quadratic formula yields

$\alpha = \dfrac{1}{2}(-1  \pm \sqrt 5); \tag 7$

since we know no more about $x$ and $y$, the best we can do is, from (1), write

$x = \alpha y, \tag 8$

i.e.,

$x =  (\dfrac{1}{2}(-1  \pm \sqrt 5))y; \tag 9$

curiously enough, since

$(\dfrac{1}{2}(-1  + \sqrt 5))(\dfrac{1}{2}(-1  - \sqrt 5)) = -1, \tag{10}$

we may also write

$y = -(\dfrac{1}{2}(-1  \pm \sqrt 5))x. \tag{11}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider your equation, as a quadratic equation with respect to the variable $y$ :

$$-y^2 + xy + x^2$$

handling the variable $x$ as a parameter.

Then, it would be :

$$D=b^2-4ac=x^2+4x^2=5x^2$$

It's easy to check that $\forall x\in \mathbb R, D\geq 0$, so you can safely express $y$ with respect to $x$ via the solution of the quadratic equation, without worrying about complex numbers.

Then :

$$y_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt D}{2a} \Rightarrow y_{1,2} = \frac{-x+\sqrt{5x^2}}{-2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y-x}{x}$$
$$x^2=y(y-x)$$
$$x^2=y^2-yx$$
$$x^2+yx=y^2$$
$$x^2+yx+\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2=y^2+\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2=\frac{5}{4}y^2$$
$$x+\frac{y}{2}=\pm\sqrt{5}\frac{y}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{y}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{5})$$

Comment: So indeed $y = \varphi x$ right?

Comment: Way more straightforward by quadratic form though. Be careful about square roots and square powers too.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui What do you mean exactly? If y is just a constant multiple of x?

Comment: No the golden ratio

Comment: @Rebellos yes, of course. But it might be spectacular this way.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui yes.